# jQuery ajax POST request for log in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to write a `.ajax` request through a form to log in. When I submit my form, nothing happens with either the `success` or `error` functions. I notice that if I put an alert box after the `.ajax` call it does not work either. I would expect, that if I am just incorrectly putting the data, I would at least expect the error alert box to show up? Here is my code:

```
var clientType = "clienttype"; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").submit(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myurl",
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&client_type=" + clienttype, 
            success: function(data) {
                alert("sent" + data);  
            }, 
            error: function(){
                alert("Did not work");  
            }
        }); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Sounds like your submit event isn't working, not the ajax request. that, or... the page is reloading, i guess.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: Add the HTML form code. Also, please specify errors, or issues you experience.

Comment: None, actually. If I put an alert box before the ajax request, it works, so I'm pretty sure the submit is fine.

Comment: Yea, your page is reloading.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? If I put the alert within the submit function and submit the form the alert works.

Comment: Right. And then the ajax request is sent, but before it is finished, the form submits the default way and reloads the page.

Comment: Don't use alerts to debug code. Use the browser's developer tools. See what errors you get there and look at the network tab to see what's going between the client and server

Comment: I see, should I not put my ajax request inside of the submit function? Like I said, the console on the browser dev tools is blank.

Comment: Can you show us the server side code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're already using JQuery. So perhaps use the built in `post` function. Example below:

Also side note: You've got a slight type in your variable: `data: $(this).serialize() + "&client_type=" + clienttype,` clienttype was declared with a capital T: `clientType`

```
var clientType = "clienttype"; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("myurl",{data:$(this).serialize(),client_type:clientType},function(data){
            console.log("Date returned from request:",data);
            // Returns JSON Data. So data.clientType.
        },'json');

    });
});
```

Comment: Wow once that typo was fixed, my error function worked. Now I just need to figure out why it's failing. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any backend code or example responses I could possibly help better if I knew what the serverside was.

Comment: Yea I don't have access to the actual server side code, but I know the API's work because I tested them on a RESTful client utility. The error I'm now getting on chrome dev tools is a 404 not found.

Comment: Then that means there is a fault with the URL, or it could be a cross-origin error. Is this a public API, I could try it myself.

Comment: I may not understand what the "data" parameter is. That is what we want to send the server correct?

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` will take the form and turn it into a JSON string for the server side to parse.

Answer (score 0):

If you add in a trigger to cancel the page from being submitted, it should work (return false;), take a look below.

```
var clientType = "clienttype"; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myurl",
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&client_type=" + clienttype, 
            success: function(data) {
                alert("sent" + data);  
            }, 
            error: function(){
                alert("Did not work");  
            }
        });

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I added `.preventDefault()` which I believe does the same as your answer. It is still not doing anything.